# powerpoint 2010 can I add a header to my presentation

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

can I add a header to my presentation.. option in headers and footers seems to be footers only or a header to notes and handouts not the presentation?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Powerpoint [slide master](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/create-and-customize-a-slide-master-HA010078011.aspx).

Whatever is put on the slide master appears on every slide. You can select to omit the title page, though. The slide master is also useful for placing automatic slide numbers.